# Google Analytics: How to see the breakdown of custom definition for a specific event?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have Google Analytics set up for my React Native app (iOS/Android). I have a custom event `create_item` with a custom dimension `category`.

In the Google Analytics dashboard under `Engagement > Events > create_item`, I can see in the `EVENTS IN LAST 30 MINUTES` panel that the custom dimensions are being passed to GA correctly.

How can I see the breakdown of `category` for this `create_item` event (ideally something like a pie chart or bar chart), or custom dimensions that happened over 30 minutes ago? I've been trying and failing to set it up from the `Explorations > Free Form` tab.